# How do GWT PlaceHistoryMapper tokens translate to actual URLs?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-places

If I implement my own `PlaceHistoryMapper`:

```
public class MyAppPlaceHistoryMapper implements PlaceHistoryMapper {
    @Override
    public Place getPlace(String token) {
        if(token.equals("home"))
            return new HomePlace();
        else
            return new AboutUsPlace();
    }

    @Override
    public String getToken(Place place) {
        if(place instanceof HomePlace)
            return "home";
        else
            return "about-us";
    }}
}
```

And if my web app is rooted at `http://www.myapp.com`, then what are the actual (bookmarkable) URLs associated with `HomePlace` and `AboutUsPlace`? Are they:

- `http://www.myapp.com/home` and `http://www.myapp.com/about-us`; or
- `http://www.myapp.com/HomePlace:home` and `http://www.myapp.com/AboutUsPlace:about-us`; or
- something else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `http://www.myapp.com/#home` and `http://www.myapp.com/#about-us`.

If you prefer, you can also have `http://www.myapp.com/#HomePlace:home` and `http://www.myapp.com/#AboutUsPlace:about-us`. To achieve that, you would use [PlaceTokenizers and @WithTokenizers](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces#PlaceHistoryMapper) instead of implementing PlaceHistoryMapper yourself.

Both approaches are good, it's your choice.